# How to use the same structure accross multiple source files?

Tags: c, struct, compilation, header-files

I have 3 source files: matrix.c, tetramino.c and learntris.c (which includes the headers `tetramino.h` and `matrix.h`, linking it with the respective files). I have a structure: `struct tetramino` that is need in all these files. After reading this question and its answers- [How to use a defined struct from another source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041797/how-to-use-a-defined-struct-from-another-source-file), I created a header file `structure.h` and now my files look like this:

In structure.h:

```
typedef struct tetramino  
{
  int type;
  char *p;
}tetramino;
```

In matrix.h:

```
#include"structure.h"
int print_matrix(void);
int clear_matrix(void);
```

In tetramino.h:

```
#include"structure.h"
int rotate(void);
int set_tetramino(void);
```

And finally, in the main learntris.c file contains:

```
#include"structure.h"
#include"matrix.h"
#include"tetramino.h"
```

Now, upon compiling them, I get these errors:

> error: redefinition of 'struct tetramino'

and

> error: conflicting types for 'tetramino'

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you `#include <structure.h>` in all of your files, it includes them each time. This causes it to try to define the structure each time.

Use include guards to ensure that the header file will be included once.

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H
#define STRUCTURE_H

typedef struct tetramino  
{
  int type;
  char *p;
}tetramino;

#endif /* STRUCTURE_H */
```

It is suggested to use guards in all your header files, however this is not a must, but a very good practice.

---

As stated by Neroku, you could use `#pragme once` instead. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6793411/2411320).

Comment: use `#pragma once` as *include guard* instead

Answer (score 2):

Besides guards, that other answers explain, it is not good practice to include .h files in .h files as you now cannot control the order in which they are included. Also, a change to a .h file can now result in all your c files needing recompilation, even if they are not affected by the change (that is, you create unnecesary dependencies).

You should have included `structure.h` *only* in the C files and then *only* when the C file needs to know about the structure.

Comment: "and then only when it needs to know about the structure"- can you please elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: "not good practice to include .h files"- then what exactly can these files contain?

Comment: "cannot control the order in which they are included"- Isn't the file that is named first, included first too? I mean if I write `#include"structure.h"` before `#include"matrix.h"`, doesn't it mean that structure.h will get included before matrix.h?

Comment: With "cannot control the order in which they are included" I mean that some C files may need a different order in which the .h files are included than other C files.

Answer (score 1):

Every header file [should have the following structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

```
#ifndef TETRAMINO_STRUCTURE_H
#define TETRAMINO_STRUCTURE_H

struct tetramino { ... };

#endif
```

This means that the main part of the header file is only evaluated once. The name `TETRAMINO_STRUCTURE_H` consists of the project name, the file name and the trailing `H`, meaning *header*.

Second, since the function declarations don't need the `tetramino` type, you don't need to `#include "structure.h"` in them. You only need these lines in the corresponding `.c` files.

Comment: "Every header file needs the following structure:" -- no. Although this is the most common use case, there are some good uses for headers without guard macros as well.

Comment: Agreed, my response is too simple. But when beginners follow this advice, it won't do much harm to them, therefore I thought it would be ok.

Comment: it's good advice to beginners of course, I'd just rephrase it to something like "you should always use the following [...]", so it's not the "bad kind of simplification" (the one that makes it incorrect) :)

Answer (score 1):

`#include` literally pastes the contents of the included file into the location of the `#include` directive. So in your example, you end up with 3 times the same structure declaration.

The canonic solution for this is guard macros:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_HEADER_FILE_H
#define EXAMPLE_HEADER_FILE_H

struct exampleStruct
{
    // ...
};

#endif
```

This way, only the first `#include` will actually paste the declaration, every consecutive `#include` will cause  the preprocessor to skip the whole header because the guard macro is already defined.

Comment: But all these header files also contain `#include<stdio.h>` and `#include<stdlib.h>`. How come they not produce any errors?

Comment: because all standard headers also use guard macros where needed?